# Multithreaded windows service stop working

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, task-parallel-library

I am using windows service to generate report say around 2K report. I am also using TPL for performance gain. I observed that on local machine it works fine for 40 report, but on UAT for 2K it does not work properly, it stop working abnormally and windows service state is started. No event log entry in system event viewer (I assume I am not getting event log entry because service state is started and it does not terminate abnormally)

Here is my code block.

```
 foreach (pt_report report in reportCollection)
 {

    using(dbContent context=new dbContext())
    {
       //Execute 1 sp which takes around 2 minutes.
       //do some db operation to update status of sp execution.
      //This step is mandatory for all 2K plan before running Async task.

    }
    if(report.Status != Completed) //check for completion of report generation
    {
        Task generateReport = new Task(delegate
        {
           ScheduleMassReportGeneration(report); // This takes around 2-3 min more to generate pdf.
        });
        generateReport.Start();
        //Problem #1 occurs (see below description).
    }
 }
```

## Problem #1:

I understand that when the async task started I need to write something to hook up the thread so that I can check the status of execution. Based on the above code I don't have any control over it, it's like orphan now. Now I would like to take control over it so that I can check what happen that thread/task and log appropriate status to db and re-run those task.

PS: Proper logging is written in `ScheduleMassReportGeneration()` method() to track what's going on while generating report. But I didn't see any sign of error or suspicious thing.
It's just slip away without leaving any traces.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `it depends`...

Generally when you want to start the Task and have control over it, than you can use

```
await Task.Run(() => ScheduleMassReportGeneration(report));
```

But it seems like report generation in your case is CPU intensive and in such cases, delegating the `work` to tasks may not bring benefits, since there is nothing that can be done while generating report.


If reports are something that can be processed in parallel, than you can create task for each report and in the end wait for all of them to finish:

```
var tasks = reportCollection.Where(r => r.Status != Completed)
    .Select(r => Task.Run(() => ScheduleMassReportGeneration(r)))
    .ToArray();

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

## Edit1

The reason why the service starts and ends quickly is because it does everything it is expected to. It simply creates tasks and then it finishes.

Comment: Thanks @Tomas, But need to execute 1 sp before async operation. I just edited my question for better understanding.